# What are the requirements of naturalisation in Germany?

Tags: germany, citizenship

I am living in Germany and I want to know what are the requirements to get a German citizenship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The German Federal Office for Migration and Refugees](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Einbuergerung/InDeutschland/indeutschland-node.html) lists the criteria to be meet:

> - you have an unrestricted right of residence at the time of being naturalised,
> - you have passed the naturalisation test (knowledge of the legal and social system, as well as living conditions in Germany),
> - your habitual, lawful place of residence has been in Germany for eight years (this period can be reduced to seven years if you attend
>     an integration course successfully, and can be reduced to as few as
>     six years in the case of special integration measures),
> - you have independent means of securing a living (including for family members entitled to maintenance) without resorting to welfare
>     payments and unemployment benefit II,
> - you have adequate German-language skills,
> - you do not have any convictions on account of a criminal offence,
> - you are committed to the free democratic constitutional order of the Basic Law of the Federal Republic of Germany, and
> - you have lost or given up your former nationality (exceptions apply with regard to this point, depending on the country of origin;
>     please contact the naturalisation authority).